# Check if Cells in Range include a string, then if it does, average the numbers found in specific cells in the same row as those cells

Tags: google-sheets

So, Im currently trying to make a google sheet where I can Input Data, and then calculate points based on different criteria of the Input.
The relevant Part of the Input Data would look something like this:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple, Banana, Orange | something else | 4 | Fig, Grapefruit | something else | 2 |
| Orange, Fig, Grapefruit | something else | 3 | Banana | something else | 1 |

Now what I want to do is for example check all cells in the column A and D for 'Banana' and then average the points in C and F for which the cell in the same row contains banana. The Cells in B and E contains other data that I will use, but it will sort itself out once I manage to do this.

Obviously I already checked the Internet for this solution. I tried using regexmatch, search and find, and all of them didnt work as intended.

Right now I have: `=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(SUM(IF(A:D = "Banana";C:F)))/COUNTIF(A:B; "Banana");-1)`

This does not work though, in this example it would just output 1, but I want it to say 2,5. Surrounding the word with * did not work, it just outputs 0. It works when I just want to check for a word using *, but when I also let it add the numbers, it doesnt anymore, and I dont know why.

I would therefore like to know how I would solve this, because I tried everything I could think of.

Comment: Can you please attach a copy of your Google Sheet as this is quite difficult to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=query({A:C;D:F};"select AVG(Col3) where Col1 like '%Banana%' ")
```

[image]

Comment: Mike, based on the post's formula example, this poster appears to be in a location where semicolons are used instead of commas.

Comment: Correct! I have changed my answer Thx Erik

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked. A problem I had was that I didnt really want it to take up 2 cells, but with `=index(query({A:C;D:F};"select AVG(Col3) where Col1 like '%Banana%' "); 2)` that was solved as well. Now it works exactly as intended. Thank You.